# Why are there four ways of writing 黄?

Tags: word-choice, characters, word, character-identification, word-lists

My keyboard does not allow me to input them all but I have found four (similar) ways in total of writing the Chinese character for yellow (黄). Why is this and how have these four forms come to differ?

Comment: Highly related: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/33475/when-handwriting-%e9%bb%84-hu%c3%a1ng-yellow-is-it-incorrect-to-have-a-disconnected-%e8%8d%89-c%c7%8eo/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## 黄

Simplifed variant (Unicode point U+9ec4)

## 黃

Traditional variant (Unicode point U+9ec3)

## ⿈

Kangxi radical 201 (Unicode point U+2fc8)

Variant character (Unicode point U+2155b)

Variant character (Unicode point U+28774)

Comment: Thanks, but I can only see the first two characters (on the Android SE app). Why is this?

Comment: Because those are the only ones you would need in a non-specialized context. That is simplified and traditional. The other ones are rather special, and you would need some more powerful fonts that are not available for phones.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [Variant Dictionary](http://dict2.variants.moe.edu.tw/variants/). They are all variants to 黃.

Characters in Chinese are progressing. Different fonts and writing ways can also make characters change.

**UPDATE:**

Another reference [Moe Dictionary](https://www.moedict.tw/%E9%BB%83) here. It shows every word's pronouncing and meaning by hovering your cursor on it.

Answer (score 0):

The display font maybe doesn't have these variant characters. Try using a different font

Comment: How do I change the font? Can pictures be posted of the variants instead? Thanks.