# What is the signature and red seal on my landscape painting? (Characters identified: 廣城作)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

The painting shows a landscape with trees, boats on water, and a mountain in the background.

[image: photo]

Answer (score 5):

#### [Regular script transcription](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%9A%B8%E5%AE%9A)

[image: Regular script transcription]

The [cursive calligraphy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursive_script_(East_Asia)) says

```
作廣
　城
```

> Work of 廣城 (Mandarin Pinyin: **Guǎng Chéng**)

The seal says

```
⿸厂 （廣）
    （城）
```

> 廣城

Where 廣城 is the artist's name (probably using a [pseudonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudonym)).

---

#### Notes on seal character identification

##### ⿸厂（廣）

「廣」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*kʷˤaŋʔ/**, *large hall* > *wide, expansive*) is comprised of semantic [「广」 (*building*)](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=26720) and phonetic 「黃」 (**/*qʷˤaŋ/**, [now written as 「尪」](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/33478/18338)).

This variation of 「廣」 corrupts 「广」 into 「厂」, and corrupts 「黃」 into 「」, probably by something like the following sequence:

<kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image: 黃]
耳尊
[集成6007](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=6007&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image: 黃]
33
包山竹簡</kbd>
<kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image]
[黃部・古文](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77392&page=68)
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
<kbd>[隸定](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%9A%B8%E5%AE%9A)
[image]</kbd>

##### （城）

「城」 (**/*[d]eŋ/**, *city walls*) is comprised of semantic 「土」 (*ground*, indicating *a place to be defended*) and simultaneously semantic and phonetic 「成」 (which is the original form of 「城」).

Earlier variations of 「城」 used semantic [「」 (*outer city wall*](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=21597), now written as 「郭」) instead.

<kbd>西周
金
[image]
班簋
[集成4341](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=4341&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
金
[image]
4.2677
金文總集</kbd>
<kbd>篆
[image]
[土部・籀文](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77392&page=63)
說文解字</kbd>
<kbd>隸定
[image]</kbd>